# PHP parsing simple_html_dom

Tags: php, parsing

I am stuck with a semi-hard problem with 'simple html dom' (php class used for html parsing). I've used it many times before so I know how to do simple parsing. PROBLEM:

```
$k=0;
for ($k = 0; $k < 15; $k++)
{
    $link[$k] = 'www.example.com/' . $test[1][$k];
    print ($link[$k]);
    $test = file_get_html ('$link[$k]');
    echo($test);
}
```

What is the answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in [string declarations with single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) are not expanded to the values they represent. So `'$link[$k]'` is actually the plain value `$link[$k]`. But actually you don’t need any quotes at all:

```
$test = file_get_html($link[$k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem:

```
$test = file_get_html('$link[$k]');
```

Remove the quotes:

```
$test = file_get_html($link[$k]);
```